# Photoshop file in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

I have created one (8.5"x11") file in Photoshop. And from view-new guide layout i have split tht file into three parts.
But when i open tht file in illustrator i found that as a one rectangle not splitted equally at all. So i select the entire rectangle want to split it from object path-split into grid!
But its grayed out.
I dont understand why illustrator behaves this way. Please help.
[image]

Comment: You can't use `Path > Split into Grid` on anything other than a **path**. A placed **raster image** is *not* a path.

Comment: tht means either i have to use Photoshop or illustrator to finish ny project. i cant use them both?

Comment: A placed raster image is not a path-- i understand this line. but when i draw a rectangle in illustrator is tht a path too?? i thought path is only line which is  drawn with pen tool....

Comment: A *shape* (rectangle, circle, star, polygon, etc) is a closed *path*. A raster images is a raster image and has *no* path. Split Into Grid works on closed paths.

Comment: Why do you need to split up the image? Do you need to use the image in Illustrator for a layout of some kind? Or are you just trying to split the image up into separate files?

Comment: actually my client wants it to be done in Photoshop. so i attempted to create that trifold in photoshop.(which i nvr did before, i always use illustrator) .. i work in illustrator that way i mentioned! (take a rectangle 8.5"x11", split it into three parts, design separately..bla bla bla) so i wanted to do the Photoshop part (photo manipulation,layer masking, blending etc) in photshop and the text part in illustrator! but now am in hell!! i didn know what scott had mentioned!

Comment: Thank you both any way :'(

Comment: am a self learner. you may find my ways are wrong. kindly show me if you see any. i will b grateful eternally.

Answer (score 0):

You can cut the image in photoshop into the 3rds for the trifold and bring each one into illustrator in the artboards. Another method is to lay the image into the background and design the text over the top after you setup the trifold in illustrator. I've also built small bi-fold catalogs in photoshop. If your resolution is high enough the text can look very good. You have quite a few options - good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much. am feeling so helpless.. Thank you again.